# Game Crashes When Changing Scenes

Tags: scene

I've recently created a game were a small robot chases you, it uses a lot of Vertices (Approximately: 300000). When I open the .exe for the game the menu pops up, no problem, but when I click 'Play' the game crashes! If I remove the Menu Scene everything works fine, every now and then it won't crash. But I want to bring down the crash rate to a solid 10%. I can't give anyone the file since a lot of textures and objects may be missing. Is there anyway I can stop these crashes?

Comment: Does it work when running inside blender?

Comment: have you tried to reduce poly count and verified that behaves better? low poly modeling is typical in real-time games... there are tricks and tools to fake higher details for gaming usage...